# Import only certain parts of .dxf files

Tags: pyqgis, dxf

I would like to know, whether and how it is possible to import only certain layers of a .dxf file. I made a code which imports all points and lines. However, this code can only import everything at once.

At the moment, I simply delete everything unwanted from my .dwg AutoCAD file before I export it. However if its possible to only import certain layers like for exaple 'Boreholes' and 'Anomalies', it would greatly increase efficiency.

I use QGIS version 2.8.8 'Wien'

Comment: If you can upgrade to QGIS 3, you can select layers in Project -> Import/Export -> Import layers from DWG/DXF.

Comment: >>  _made a  **code** which imports all points and lines_:

Which code / which module do you use? OGR?